# Add a cookie once flash banner is loaded on a web page

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I want to add a cookie once flash banner is loaded on a web page.
I have the javascript code inside html tags and I want to use it in .fla file using Actionscript3. Below is the Javascript code in html tags. How can I do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
adroll_adv_id = "JD5ZGBNO4RBYVAMMMPX3J7";
adroll_pix_id = "CEJOJM5N5VAHBKCVMT2DML";
(function () {
var oldonload = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){
__adroll_loaded=true;
var scr = document.createElement("script");
var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://s.adroll.com" : "http://a.adroll.com");
scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
scr.type = "text/javascript";
scr.src = host + "/j/roundtrip.js";
((document.getElementsByTagName('head') || [null])[0] ||
document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode).appendChild(scr);
if(oldonload){oldonload()}};
}());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will not be able to know when a swf file is loaded from the outside, the call must be done from the inside with ExternalInterface

```
ExternalInterface.call("loadCookie()");
```

In the particular case that you CAN NOT modify the SWF (you don't have the sources) what you can do is create your own swf with the exact same dimensions that this banner, and in this new swf, in the code, you listen for a Loader

```
_loader = new Loader();
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteContentLoaderInfo);
```

and then you fire the ExternalInterface call to Javascript.